# Knitr to PDF Does Not Honor Line Breaks?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have a Rnw file that has a simple code chunk:

```
<<echo = TRUE, tidy = TRUE>>=
getNormIntegral = function(x, sd = 1) {
  res = pnorm(x*sd, sd = sd) - pnorm(-1*x*sd, sd = sd)  
  return(1.0 - res)
}
@
```

This looks good here, but when I render it to a pdf file using knitr, the code collapses into a single line and runs past the box.  I have tried to set the width option with the following:

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
  options(width=10)
@
```

but that did not have an affect.  The resulting output in the pdf is:

[image]

(Ok, it is not extending past the box boundaries, but it is not honoring the manual line breaks that I put in the code...)

Any suggestions to make the output look like the code chunk that I typed in?

(I should add that I am using R 3.1.2, RStudio 0.99.34, and knitr 1.7)

Comment: What happens with TIDY = FALSE?

Answer (score 1):

Just set `tidy=FALSE`in the chunk options. knitr automatically tidies your code.

Comment: Does not fix the issue, nothing is different.

Comment: I am concerned your toy example isn't showing everything. The other thing to do is `opts_chunk$set(tidy = FALSE)`

Comment: Ok... you are right...  I put that code block in an empty Rnw file and it rendered correctly...  Time to start debugging, thanks for the push...

Comment: Ok, this looks like it is because I am passing the code block through a LaTeX macro that I wrote that is clobbering it...  I think I will need to post this as a new question and not continue it here.

Comment: Question reposted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792648/knitr-code-chunks-lose-formatting-when-passed-as-arguments-to-latex-function

Comment: @JustaceClutter You deleted that post, but I strongly believe you should delete this post and keep that one, because this post did not provide a minimal reproducible example, and that one did.